# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException 'No route to host' on local network address?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to connect to one of mine IOT ESP32 based web server from Xamarin Android native based project with the following code:

```
client = new HttpClient();
                
Uri uri = new Uri( "http://192.168.0.5/sensors" );
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync( uri ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
{
    string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Yet seems like the timout is ignored, and with or without it I am receiving

> **System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:** 'No route to host'

- How to properly connect from Xamarin Android native app to an address inside my local network ?
- What is causing this exception ?

Comment: this is a networking problem.  Your device can't determine how to reach the server.  Are they on the same subnet?  Can you reach the server from the device browser?

Comment: from my PC I have no issue getting date from the server, but from the mobile - nope.
It is connected to the same router which my PC and the server is.

Comment: as I said, this is really a networking issue, not a programming problem.

Comment: Not sure I do understand how it is possible to be a network issue. Please explain.

Comment: "No route to host" is a network error.  If the browser on the device cannot reach the server, that is a networking issue.   There is nothing you can do in your code to fix it.    It is a networking configuration issue.  Check your router, check your firewall, check your server config, etc.

Comment: None of these apply, except the Android itself have some absurd bug with the local networks. The connection work flawlessly on MacOS, Windows, ESP32, ESP8266, Arduino and Iothingy. Only Android refusing.

Comment: Btw, found out that there is quite a lot of peoples having similar issue, which is never received any actual answer on "why it is happening", so probably it is really an internal Android bug.

Comment: Have you tried to use a network security configuration XML file to allow clear text traffic? See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network is all fine, and the server is reachable from practically any other OS, including microcontrollers within it except Android.

- **Found workaround** - redirecting port from the router to the server, and using external IP on this port seems like working.